# ActiveRecord 3.1.0 multiple databases

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to upgrade the ActiveRecord gem to the latest 3.1.0 release and seeing a lot of exceptions being raised, I think it's due to how we handle multiple databases.

For each of our databases we specify a separate base class which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, and call `establish_connection` in there.  There are no cross-database relations.  This has worked fine for us up until now.

Having upgraded to ActiveRecord 3.1.0 I'm seeing that it fails with an `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished` exception, when traversing relations (i.e. it will successfully pull a single entity or set of them from the DB, but fails when navigating to a related class).

The top line of the backtrace is `C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in 'retrieve_connection'`, so I dug into this a little.  The method is defined as follows:

```
def retrieve_connection(klass) #:nodoc:
    pool = retrieve_connection_pool(klass)
    (pool && pool.connection) or raise ConnectionNotEstablished
end
```

My simple test (`puts Customer.first.address`) calls `retrieve_connection` 3 times.  Twice with `Customer` as the `klass` parameter, and once with `ActiveRecord::Base` as the parameter - which is when it fails as `establish_connection` has not been called for `ActiveRecord::Base`.

To the *actual question* then - is there a new recommended way of handling multiple database connections in ActiveRecord?  If so, what is it?

If not, what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue yesterday while upgrading to ActiveRecord 3.1.0.  I can't speak to whether there is a new recommended way of handling multiple database connections in ActiveRecord 3.1, but I did find a way to unblock myself.

It appears a connection must now be established on ActiveRecord::Base in order for it to determine the table name lengths/rules of the adapter.  Along with the rest of my connections established in my database initializer, I now also have an ActiveRecord::Base connection established to one of my DBs (it doesn't matter which one).

I'd like to think there's a better solution to be found, but I'm happy to be unblocked for now.

Comment: Thanks for that, haven't had time to try it out yet but it sounds like a good solution!  Please come back and let us know if you find a better way...

Comment: We've run into the same problem and would love to find a better solution. Thanks for the help, though. At least we're unblocked now as well!

Comment: Ran into this problem myself (activerecord 3.1.3) and have resolved the problem as suggested.  I agree a better solution would be more ideal.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this solution - What I was seeing was that when establish_connection was called in each of the OtherDb classes - there seemed to be alot of overhead reloading table definitions and I would randomly see issues every time the class def was reloaded.

```
# The idea here is to specify that a given model should use another
# database without having to change the entire inheritance hierarchy

# declare model for table in primary connection
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  # assume we have logic here that we don't want to refactor into a module
  # but we do want to inherit in OtherDb::Bar
end

module Foo

  # base model in Foo namespace - uses another db
  class BaseConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
    # OtherDb::Title.database contains a db config hash
    # This would probably go in the initializers
    establish_connection OtherDb::Title.database 
  end

  # module used to override db connection
  module OtherDb::Base
    def retrieve_connection
      # connection_handler.retrieve_connection(self) #  normal behavior
      connection_handler.retrieve_connection(Foo::BaseConnection) # use db from Foo::BaseConnection
    end
  end

  # Foo::Bar is identical to ::Bar but is in another db
  class Bar < ::Bar
    extend OtherDb::Base
  end
end
```