# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished for Rails3 mysql for rake db:migrate on EC2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, amazon-ec2, rake

On Amazon's EC2 using Ubuntu, when I execute **rake db:migrate** as:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production" --trace
```

I get the error **ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished** as shown below

```
 ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
 ** Invoke environment (first_time)
 ** Execute environment
 ** Execute db:migrate
 rake aborted!
 ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:316:in `retrieve_connection'
```

I can login to mysql with the username and password in my config/database.yml file
and the database is there. So mysql is running, and that is not the problem.

My config/database.yml file looks like:

```
 production:
   adapter: mysql2
   encoding: utf8
   reconnect: false
   database: app_production
   pool: 5
   username: root
   password: password
   host: localhost
   socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Here are my gems from gem list:

```
 abstract (1.0.0)
 actionmailer (3.0.3)
 actionpack (3.0.3)
 activemodel (3.0.3)
 activerecord (3.0.3)
 activeresource (3.0.3)
 activesupport (3.0.3)
 arel (2.0.10)
 builder (2.1.2)
 bundler (1.0.10 ruby)
 cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
 daemons (1.0.10)
 erubis (2.6.6)
 eventmachine (0.12.10)
 fastthread (1.0.7)
 gem_plugin (0.2.3)
 i18n (0.6.0)
 mail (2.2.19)
 mime-types (1.17.2)
 mongrel (1.2.0.pre2)
 mysql2 (0.2.7)
 polyglot (0.3.3)
 rack (1.2.5)
 rack-mount (0.6.14)
 rack-test (0.5.7)
 rails (3.0.3)
 railties (3.0.3)
 rake (0.9.2.2)
 rmagick (2.13.1)
 thin (1.2.7)
 thor (0.14.6)
 treetop (1.4.10)
 tzinfo (0.3.31)
 xmpp4r (0.5)
```

The error in connection_pool.rb is happening at the same place as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390623/activerecord-3-1-0-multiple-databases) whose answer says that a connection needs to be established on ActiveRecord::Base.  The code is failing in connection_pool.rb because it is getting sent klass = ActiveRecord::Base which doesn't have a connection.  So I tried creating a model my_connection_base.rb that looks like the following

```
 require 'active_record'

 class MyConnectionBase < ActiveRecord::Base

      MyConnectionBase.establish_connection(
        :adapter => "mysql2",
        :host => "localhost",
        :username => "<your database username>",
        :password => "<your database password>",
        :database => File.dirname(__FILE__) + "app_production"
      )
   self.abstract_class = true
 end
```

And then all of my models inherit MyConnectionBase as in role.rb below:

```
require 'my_connection_base'

class Role < MyConnectionBase
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

But I still get ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished when I try to run a migration.  Is there something else I need to do with Rails 3 to ensure that the connection is made to mysql before performing the migration?

Comment: Is `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` the actual location of the MySQL socket? I troubleshot this issue last week to find that it was actually in `/tmp/mysqld.sock`.

Comment: @Michael - that was one of the first things I checked.  The actual socket is /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock and /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock is a link to it, i.e. ls -l /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock gives: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.  Which brings up the question, how can I check that the socket is working correctly?

Comment: If you can connect on the command line, the socket is probably working correctly.

Comment: @Michael - There is no file at /tmp/mysqld.sock.

Comment: @Michael - yes, that is the thing that confuses me is that I can connect to mysql on the command line fine.  I also granted the permissions on the database as - grant all on app_production.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the migrations to work by adding **db:create** to the rake command line as shown below:

```
 bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
```

I don't know why db:create is needed now.  One thing I didn't mention is that these migrations were transferred from a Rails 2 application to a Rails 3 application.  I'm still having trouble creating pages in the migration, as shown below in the Page.create section that I commented out:

20101014205123_create_pages.rb

```
 class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     create_table :pages do |t|
       t.column :title, :string
       t.column :permalink, :string
       t.column :body, :text
       t.column :created_at, :datetime
       t.column :updated_at, :datetime
       t.timestamps
     end

 #   Page.create(:title => "Home",
 #               :permalink => "welcome-page",
 #               :body => "Welcome to Home")

   end

   def self.down
     drop_table :pages
   end
 end
```

It also looks like the initial data creation can be done in db/seeds.rb which is where I transfered the Page.create code.  I am still trying to get that to work using:

```
 bundle exec rake db:create db:seed RAILS_ENV="production" --trace
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
 uninitialized constant Page
```

I was able to fix this error by requiring the model in db/seeds.rb as shown below:

```
require File.expand_path('../../app/models/page', __FILE__)

Page.create(:title => "Home",
            :permalink => "welcome-page",
            :body => "Welcome to Home")
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue while upgrading a site from Rails2 to Rails3.  Though I haven't yet found a solution, I did notice that running `rake db:migrate:status` reports "development database is not configured".  If dig into the rails code, I find that the configurations, in fact, have not been set in ActiveRecord::Base at this point.  It seems that somewhere db:create is picking up that configuration where db:migrate is not.  I'm going to keep investigating.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the same issue as you, I did some digging (as my comment on your answer below mentions).

As it turns out, the basic piece I was missing was in my `config/environment.rb`, I was using

```
MyApp::Application.initialize
```

which was not throwing an error when it tried to read my poorly migrated `environments/{development,test, ...}.rb` files.   I replaced the initialize call with

```
MyApp::Application.initialize!
```

Then the `db:migrate` call started failing with errors that showed the *real issues* (which were getting swallowed by the `initialize` (without a bang) calls).  My `config/development.rb` file was not written properly, also probably a result of the rails2 => rails3 migration.

The reason the `db:create` saved the day is only because it does the `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` setup and doesn't depend on the environment to load that stuff so it was not failing while trying to read my faulty environments/ files.

After getting my environment files up to speed, I was on my way.

I hope this helps.